# Script to find out which disk a nearby (LAN) Mac computer is booted off?

Tags: macos, boot, mac, script, apple-remote-desktop

I have a headless Mac (OS X 10.13.6) on my LAN which sometimes reboots, and when it does, it occasionally boots off the wrong internal disk. I want to be able to check periodically, from my other machine, via a script, what boot disk a given host is using (and fire off a notification email when that happens).  Is there a command (perhaps related to Apple Remote Desktop or some profiling function) that can let me ask another local machine what its boot drive currently is? I have full admin privileges on both machines.

Comment: Do the volumes have different names? If so, you can use `stat -f '%Y %N' /Volumes/* | sed -n 's@^/ /Volumes/@@p'` to get the name of the startup volume. But first I'd spend some time trying to figure out why it doesn't always boot from the same volume. Is it properly selected in System Preferences -> Startup Disk? Is the selected disk sometimes taking a long time to start up (& maybe getting ready to fail) or something?

Comment: very helpful, thank you. Web page is not letting my simply up-vote for some reason.